# What would be the application of prooving inequality problems?

Tags: inequality, applications

What would be the application of prooving inequality problems or inequalities themself like this (in addition to train your mind)? They're very hard (at least for me) but as an engineer I'm curious about its application. 
  Please don't judge, I'm not a math major and just curious if they have some real applications. 
Something like complex number, integral, Laplace, Fourier transforms are very useful for engineering but I don't know if these inequalities would be used somehow for EE or some real applications. 
Please note that I don't want to just focus on the equalities in the images but I want to know about this type of equalities in general.

[image]

Or this:

[image]

And many more from [this](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/PowerOfSubstitution3.shtml) page:

[image]

Comment: I do not see any applications of this inequality.

Comment: Things aren't perfectly straight, but we pretend they are because linear formulas are so much neater.  One use for nonlinear equations is to estimate the range of $x$ for which linear equations are good enough.